# Print value from while True: in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, printing

I'm trying to print a value from this while True.

```
while True:
   variable = bool(False)
   time.sleep(6)
   variable = bool(True)
   time.sleep(6)

print(variable)
```

The print is out from the loop I Need to get the variable to use it in a for.

Comment: `while True` will never exit. Why do you need it? Just remove the `while` line.

Comment: Put the `print` line in the loop.

Comment: Use break after **time.sleep(6)** to get out of the loop

Comment: Note that `bool(False)` is the same as `False` and `bool(True)` is the same as `True`.  in fact, `bool(False) is False` and `bool(True) is True` both evaluate to `True`.  Just use `False` and `True` directly.  Using `bool(True)` makes no more sense than using `bool(bool(bool(True)))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print(variable)` statement will never be reached, to solve this you can do something like this:

```
import threading, time

variable = None
def loopFunction():
    global variable    # The loopFunction will be using the global variable defined before, without this the variable will be treated as local.
    while True:
        variable = False  # bool(False) is False
        time.sleep(6)
        variable = True   # bool(True) is True
        time.sleep(6)

# The loopFunction will be running until the program ends on a new thread
loop = threading.Thread(target = loopFunction, args = ())
loop.start()

# Rest of your code
for i in range(10):
    print(variable)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Where the loopFunction will be running on a different thread, so the rest of the code will be reached.

If you only want to check the time since the program starts, you can simply do something like:

```
import time

start = time.time()

# Rest of your code
for i in range(10):
    print((time.time()-start)%12>6)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Which will give you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print inside the loop.

```
variable = False
while True:
    print(variable)
    time.sleep(6)
    variable = not variable
```

prints:

```
False
True
False
True
False
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Do a bit of research before asking the question

First of all

```py
variable = bool(False)
```

Is not necessary, `variable = False` is the same.
`variable = eval('False')` would be more meaningful, as theres an actual conversion going on

Second, you need to break the loop if you want to exit it, but i assume your just trying to print False and True every 6 seconds

so you would do this

```py
 while True:
   variable = False
   print(variable)
   time.sleep(6)
   variable = True
   print(variable)
   time.sleep(6)
```

Comment: Not sure what you expect `bool('False')` will yield. You know that truth value of non-empty str is `True`, right?

Comment: @buran I meant `var = eval('False')` or True